Understanding of Probability density function and Radon–Nikodym derivative
In the measure-theoretic formalization of probability theory:

A random variable $X$ is defined as a measurable function $X$ from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ to a measurable space $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A})$.
The probability distribution of $X$ is the image measure $X_* \mathbb{P}$ of $X$, which is a probability measure on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A})$ satisfying $X_* \mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P} X^{-1}$.

If i have a measure $\lambda$ on $(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{A})$, and if  $X_* \mathbb{P}$ is dominated by $\lambda$ then the Radon–Nikodym derivative is the probability density of $X$. Is that correct ?
In some texts, an author describes a random variable $X$ as being distributed according to a probability density $p^*$. This implies that $p^*$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative with respect to some reference measure that induces the probability distribution of $X$.
Additionally, when an author states that all densities are assumed to be dominated by a known measure, it means that these densities are the Radon–Nikodym derivatives with respect to this measure.
Is my understanding correct ?

yes correct....

Yes. The characterization of the distribution of a random variable using the density is correct as the RN derivative is unique.
